# How to create query for my problem to sum based on date

Tags: mysql

i have problem. I need to create query to find sum all of my payment in column jumlah for each date in column tanggal

[this is my db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQq6C.png)

Comment: Please post your code here, and explain what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

use `sum() aggregation and group by`

```
select tangal,sum(jumlah) as totalpayment
from tablename
group by tangal
```